# Probing an externally powered circuit using MSP432 connected to the PC

Tags: microcontroller, grounding, msp430, texas-instruments, ground-loop

I have an circuit powered by an external SMPS and I'd like to debug it using a TI MSP432 MCU. The MCU is connected to the PC and I'll use TExaS Display software (it basically works as a cheap low-bandwidth scope for low frequencies). However, I need the MCU to be connected to the PC and the circuit to the SMPS - but the MCU does't use differential voltage measuring (it uses only the P4.4 pin as input).

So my questions are: do I need to connect both grounds (SMPS and MCU GNDs) for correct measuring (both the PC and SMPS are connected to the same power outlet)? If so, do I need to worry about groundloops/how to deal with them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of SMPS? Is it transformer isolated?

Comment: I don't think so. I only see a hi-frequency transformer inside it (I don't think its isolating the mains).

Comment: If your power supply isn't isolated, then you need to be really careful. I once had a massive failure when my scope ground created a mains short.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is Yes. You will need to have the same GND potential for your measurement device and DUT.
But you will need to be careful, as others commented, Since you mentioned power outlet, likely you mean the Mains. for correct measurement, it is not only the ground, but the Earth. when you don't have the same earth, you don't have the same "reference" ground and your measurement can be very wrong and damage your device/instruments.

Depends on the setup and how DUT is made, isolated transformer might be needed.
with your limited info, can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use an optocoupler for probing, so I don't need to connect both grounds.